# Pure CSS Tooltip: content gets cut off

Tags: css, tooltip, css-position

I'm trying to add tooltips on my forum (inside messages). It works with short tooltips:

[image: small tooltip]

But with long tooltips I get this:

[image: big tooltip]

The text is cut off. Changing the position property for `[data-tooltip]` from `relative` to `absolute` (see the code below) fixes the problem but makes the text overlap:

[image: text overlapping]

I'm using this code:

```
div.bb-tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; 
}

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  border-bottom: .6em solid black;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  background-color: black;
  border: 4px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #ffffff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip-message);
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-width: 350px;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:after,
[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML of the message:

```
very very <div class="bb-tooltip" data-tooltip data-tooltip-message="this is a long text! the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog! lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Very very long text!">looooooooonnnnnnngggggg</div> tooltip! text text text
```

*(code taken and adapted from: https://codepen.io/trezy/pen/Khnzy)*

Adding a z-index property with high value does not fix the problem. How to fix this problem?

Another problem is: for short texts (see the first image) I get the text wrap at every word. I want it to wrap only when the length gets too long.

Live sample: https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/tooltip-test.450399/

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue so we have with what to work, as the above code work as is.

Comment: I'm not able to get a snippet that reproduce the issue: the entire HTML page is complex, and I have no idea where the problem is. Simply extracting a part of the HTML page does not reproduce the problem.
But I can link you to the page of my site that I've used for testing (the second message shows the problem): https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/tooltip-test.450399/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your CSS rule(s) `.message .messageContent` and `.messageInfo` has `overflow: hidden` which cuts off a too high tooltip.

Changing both to `overflow: visible` (or remove them fully) solves the problem.

*Update*

About the text wrap at every world, update this CSS rule `[data-tooltip]:after{min-width: 100px;background-color:black;...` with a `min-width` seems to solve that.

Comment: @SpeedJack Try give tooltip a `min-width`

Comment: @SpeedJack Updated my answer with a possible solution for the word wrap

Comment: @SpeedJack If you right click an element that have an odd behavior and chose "Inspect", most browsers will popup a tool showing that elements current styles and markup, which makes it quite easy to see whats going on (and one can alter it too on the fly to see what happens)